# AngularJs ngSwitch with ngRepeatStart / End

Tags: angularjs, switch-statement, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm tring to figure out how I could us the ngSwitch with ngRepeatStart and End on two table rows, where second row is only shown when you click on the top one.

Here's what I've got and want to make work (doesn't work):

```
<tr
                    data-ng-repeat-start="user in users | filter : { name: search, active: searchActive }"
                    data-ng-click="selectUser(user)"
                    data-ng-switch on="isSelected(user)">
                    <td>{{ user.name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ user.email }}</td>
                    <td>{{ user.active }}</td>
                    <td>{{ user.dob | date: 'EEEE, dd MMMM yyyy' }}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr data-ng-repeat-end data-ng-switch-when="true">
                    <td colspan="4">
                        {{ user.description }}
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

and here's what works:

```
<tbody
                data-ng-repeat="user in users | filter : { name: search, active: searchActive }"
                data-ng-click="selectUser(user)"
                data-ng-switch on="isSelected(user)">
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ user.name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ user.email }}</td>
                    <td>{{ user.active }}</td>
                    <td>{{ user.dob | date: 'EEEE, dd MMMM yyyy' }}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr data-ng-switch-when="true">
                    <td colspan="4">
                        {{ user.description }}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
```

I would like to avoid the wrapping `tbody` tag and instead use ngRepeatStart / End.

Is there a way of modifying my first example to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use ng-switch, just use ng-show or ng-if. Here's a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/D72iXh164SPWrLM43V8T?p=preview)

### Edit

Okay, I guess if you really want you can use ng-switch, though I would suggest not doing it if all you're doing is checking true/false. Here's the updated [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/D72iXh164SPWrLM43V8T?p=preview). The trick is that the switch needs to be on the second `<tr>`, and the ng-switch-when needed to be on the `<td>`.

Now if you need each switch to be a table row, then you're just going to have to use `ng-if`. The `ng-switch` attribute needs to be on the parent of all the `ng-switch-when`'s. That's why the switch only works when you put it on `<tbody>`, or when you switch over `<td>`'s.

Comment: Thanks, but is there a way of actually doing it with the ngSwitch if I had more than two rows per iteration?

Comment: Like if ng-switch wasn't just true or false? The way it is now it's a horrible use case for ng-switch

Comment: Though I did just update that plunker to use ng-switch

Comment: That's right - there might be more than just one case for the switch.

Comment: The problem with the second plunker obviously is that no matter what we will end up with the empty tr tags. I think I will have to stick to the tbody tag in this case. Thanks